# Missing double quotes (randomly) when downloading csv file using Oauth2.0 gmail API

Tags: python, csv, gmail, gmail-api

I am downloading csv attachments from gmail that are csv reports. I am using Python 3.6.1 and the Oauth 2.0 gmail API.

There is a date column in the csv file and I hard code it's format to '%Y-%m-%d'.

When I download the csv attachment and inspect it as a text file, most times, I get the expected date format as follows (1st 3 columns of 1st 2 lines) -

```
"date","advertiser","advertiser_id", ...
"2017-05-27","Swiss.com India (UK)","29805", ...
```

However, on occasion, the quotes from the csv file are missing - I then get it as -

```
date,advertiser,advertiser_id, ...
27/05/2017,Swiss.com India (UK),29805, ...
```

In this situation, the date pattern turns out to be '%d/%m/%Y'.

There is no discernible pattern to when a file would be downloaded with the unquoted dates. Most times, if I delete the downloaded file and re-run my script, the quoted attachment is re-downloaded.

Is there a way to setup the attachment download such that the date column is downloaded in the quoted format? Or is there a way to ensure that when I read the csv (using csv.reader) I always get the date column in a certain format?

The specific method I am using to download attachments is given here -
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get (Python version). The exact code snippet is -

```
        # Get the body of this part and it's keys.
        part_body = part['body']
        part_body_keys = part_body.keys()
        ...
        if 'data' in part_body_keys:
            a_data = part_body['data']
        elif 'attachmentId' in part_body_keys:
            att_id = part_body['attachmentId']
            att = service.users().messages().attachments().get(
                        userId=user_id, messageId=message['id'],
                        id=att_id).execute()
            a_data=att['data']
        else:
            ...

        # Encode it appropriately and write it to the file.
        file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(a_data.encode('UTF-8'))
        ...
        f = open(file_name, 'wb')
        f.write(file_data)
        f.close()
```

The code snippet when reading the csv file is -

```
infile = open(file_name, mode="r", encoding='ascii', errors='ignore')
filereader = csv.reader(infile)
date_fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
…
for a_row in filereader:
    …
    try:
        rf_datetime = time.strptime(a_row[0], date_fmt)
    …
```

Any pointers would be appreciated! This script has become a key component of my business that automates our reporting process and has visibly reduced effort all around.

Regards

Nitin

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the attached csv files are in a different format themselves (or maybe there is a difference between `'data'` and `'attachmentId'`?).

To be sure, you could download them manually and check them in a text editor.

As for the quotes: for csv it doesn't make a difference if the fields are quoted or not. Only when fields contain a field separator it needs to be surrounded with quotes. But since you're using a csv reader this shouldn't matter.

As for the dates, it's probably easiest to check the date format once before the reading loop (in the first data row), and set `date_fmt` (for parsing) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Danny_ds! No - the attachment files are all in the same format i.e. csv. However, from some senders we need to use an attachmentId - my sense is that this has to do with email encoding i.e. whether it is multi-part or not. On your last comment i.e. check the date format once before entering the loop - how do I do that? If there is a date as "2017-05-06" - I wouldn't whether this is 6th May or 5th June - right?